# Getting a ValueError from an old migration even though makemigrations command seemed to detect a change in fields

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to get this change in my fields to properly update so I can work on the rest of the project. This is the model that's causing the issue currently:

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    check_in_date = models.DateField()
    check_out_date = models.DateField()
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    people = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # the people field is the issue rn

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ", " + str(self.id)
```

Previously, the people field was an ArrayField but I changed it to a CharField because it didn't need to be an array.

Here is migration 7 where I added the people field as an ArrayField

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('project_name', '0006_confirmationentry_alter_hotel_notes'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='hotel',
            name='people',
            field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(base_field=models.IntegerField(), default=list, size=None),
        ),
    ]
```

Here's migration 8 where I changed it to a CharField

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('project_name', '0007_hotel_people'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='hotel',
            name='people',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=255),
        ),
    ]
```

I've deleted/commented out the people field several times and put it back, and when I do `python3 manage.py makemigrations`, these changes are detected. But when I do `python3 manage.py migrate` it gives me this error:

```
  Applying project_name.0007_hotel_people...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/project_name/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 290, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 131, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 163, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 248, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 131, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 108, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 381, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 229, in _remake_table
    mapping[create_field.column] = self.quote_value(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 68, in quote_value
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot quote parameter value [] of type <class 'list'>
```

I feel like this may be caused by conflicting postgres and sqlite somewhere, but if so I don't know how to make it clear to the software I'm sticking to sqlite. I know ArrayField is a part of postgres and not sqlite so hopefully that's a start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is having a similar issue, I've figured it out in an obnoxiously simple way. Commented out all of the code in models and every instance of the models throughout my codes. Did `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and `python3 manage.py migrate`. Then I just uncommented it all and ran those commands again